# How to find time range in mysql given a table with "wall time"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a time string as 8:00AM, 9:00AM etc. stored in mysql table. I want to check time range, if time 11:00AM comes in between time 9:00AM - 6:00PM? How to find it out in mysql.

Time is stored as below

```
day         depart_time     return_time
Monday      9:00am          5:00pm
Wednesday   9:30am          4:30pm
Tuesday     9:00am          3:00pm
```

Comment: Do you have cases when depart time is greater than return time? E.g. depart time is 11:00 PM and return time is 1:00 AM (next day)? This makes it interesting.

Comment: @Salman A Interesting question. I would like to see a reply assuming such is *not* the case, as it can be expanded later :)

Comment: @Chauhan I cry at the model :)

Comment: @pst: actually I have an answer, only problem is with OPs data structure... strings are hard to manipulate as date/time.

Comment: Actually, my client want option to select day, depart_time and return_time. He want time selection option as 9:00AM,9:15AM,...5:00PM etc.  So in search page if users select time 4:45PM,  as 4:45PM comes in between time 9:00AM - 5:00PM. So I want to get Monday record.

Comment: @Chauhan Can the fields be modified such that the values are stored using a simple NUMERIC military-time value? E.g. `900` (an INTEGER, not TEXT, for `9am`) and `1630` (for `4:30pm`)? Then the client just needs to "display these correctly", which is a somewhat trivial operation. The simplifies the query into something very trivial (unless there is a fun case, like Salman A talks about) with no required string-manipulation trickery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT depart_time, return_time FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE CASE
WHEN STR_TO_DATE(depart_time, '%l:%i%p') < STR_TO_DATE(return_time, '%l:%i%p') THEN
    STR_TO_DATE(depart_time, '%l:%i%p') <= @check_time AND @check_time < STR_TO_DATE(return_time, '%l:%i%p')
ELSE
    NOT(STR_TO_DATE(return_time, '%l:%i%p') <= @check_time AND @check_time < STR_TO_DATE(depart_time, '%l:%i%p'))
END
```

Substitute `@check_time` with the time you want to check. This query will work across times that span over two days.

## Sample data:

```
depart_time return_time
9:00am      5:00pm
11:00pm     1:00am
```

## Sample output:

```
#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('8:59am', '%l:%i%p');
(no result)

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('9:00am', '%l:%i%p');
9:00am      5:00pm

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('11:00am', '%l:%i%p');
9:00am      5:00pm

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('4:59pm', '%l:%i%p');
9:00am      5:00pm

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('5:00pm', '%l:%i%p');
(no result)

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('10:59pm', '%l:%i%p');
(no result)

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('11:00pm', '%l:%i%p');
11:00pm     1:00am

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('12:00am', '%l:%i%p');
11:00pm     1:00am

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('12:59am', '%l:%i%p');
11:00pm     1:00am

#SET @check_time = STR_TO_DATE('1:00am', '%l:%i%p');
(no result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to convert the string data types into time. In the example below, all rows where "11:00am" is between the departure time and return time will be returned.

```
SELECT `depart_time`,
       `return_time`
FROM   `table`
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE('11:00am', '%l:%i%p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(`depart_time`, '%l:%i%p') AND STR_TO_DATE(`return_time`, '%l:%i%p')
```

The `STR_TO_DATE` function parses the string according to a specified format. In this case, it's:

- %l: The hour (1-12)
- %i: The minutes (00-59)
- %p: AM/PM

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

select TIMEDIFF ('2006-10-31 11:50:31' , '2006-10-31 11:50:01')

you need to give 24 hr format.,

SELECT SUBTIME('01:00:00.999999', '02:00:00.999998');

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but time is stored as a string. Please check my updated question.